# make command can't find gcc

Tags: compiling, gcc, make

I've searched pretty extensively for a solution, however all the ones I've found relate to not having gcc in the PATH variable, or not properly installed.

My issue is that when I run my Makefile, I get an error saying gcc cannot be found.

Makefile:

```
boot0.o: boot0.S
    gcc​ -MD -fno-builtin -nostdinc -fno-stack-protector -Os -g -m32 -I. -c -o boot0.o boot0.S
```

and the error when I run `make`:

```
gcc​ -MD -fno-builtin -nostdinc -fno-stack-protector -Os -g -m32 -I. -c -o boot0.o boot0.S
make: gcc​: Command not found
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'boot0.o' failed
make: *** [boot0.o] Error 127
```

However, when I run the command directly in the command line, it works without an issue.

Comment: Did you install it?  `sudo apt install build-essential` is usually a good First Step.

Comment: Yes it is installed `gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
`

Comment: What does `cat -A Makefile` say? I suspect a weird invisible unicode character has crept into your file (`gccM-bM-^@M-^K -MD -fno-builtin . . .`)

Comment: @steeldriver This was exactly the problem, thank you